# What is nonlinear evolution equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is nonlinear evolution equations and how to define it? Please I also want to know the some examples of NLEEs

Answer (score 1):

See [these course notes by J.K. Hunter, UC Davis, *Nonlinear Evolution Equations*.](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/notes/nonlinev.pdf)